# Cassandra CLI 'org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException'

Tags: nosql, cassandra, command-line-interface, thrift

I'm on the latest version of Cassandra 1.1.2 and already have data in my Cassandra db. I want to update the meta data of a column family through:

update column family Comment with column_metadata =  [{column_name: timestamp, validation_class: UTF8Type}];

(prior, timestamp was of IntegerType)

However, Cassandra-CLI returns:
'org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException'

When I try the command again, I get:
'org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe'

I'm running Cassandra on Ubuntu.

Comment: can u check to see if cassandra server is running. Also, can you restart cli and reconnect to the running instance?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the data stored is not compatible with the timestamp field. The timestamp field is a 0 or 8 byte long representing the time since the Unix epoch.

I recommend checking the value in CLI to ensure that it's compatible first.